# What is the difference between HP Mixed-Use-1 and Mixed-Use-3 SSD drives?

Tags: hp, ssd

The title basically says it all. The HP whitepapers simply list Mixed-Use as a general category, but under server quickspecs for most newer HP hardware, Mixed-Use-1 and Mixed-Use-3 options are available (for example, 822559-B21, and 846434-B21 - both are 800GB enterprise SAS 12g SSDs, the sole difference seems to be the 1 or 3).

What does the mixed use number indicate?

Comment: While waiting for an answer, consider asking HP. I bet they know :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Categorized by Read Intensive (RI), Mixed Use (MU), and Write
>   Intensive (WI), you can choose the right SSD that tailors to your
>   workload demands.

The difference between the two SSDs you listed is performance. The MU-3 has higher IOPS potential and write speed than the MU-1.

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! Do you happen to know if there is a difference in MTTF for the two?

Comment: Does it matter? If you're buying HP, there's always potential for a drive failure, which could be the result of any number of factors. The point is, you'll have wearout monitoring, hopefully a RAID configuration, and a warranty to replace anything that fails in the 3-year warranty period for the drive/chassis.

Comment: Given the number of disks we will be buying, MTTF actually is kind of important. Several of our datacenters/APOPs are un-manned, and more are guarded so HP techs can't easily enter the premises. Lower MTTF means I will need additional spares on hand for our remote hands-on group.